# How to setup Identity Server 4 with Authorization Code on a NativeScript application?

Tags: c#, identityserver4

I have a native script application and I wish to login with it using Identity Server 4. Right now I'm in the stages of setting up the Identity Server 4 client and I'm not 100% sure if what I have is correct or if I am missing something. All the examples I have found online are very shortcoming when it comes to talks about native applications besides the fact they all say its possible.

Here is my current implementation of the client:

```
new Client
{
    ClientId = "nativeapp",
    ClientName = "Native App Sample",
    ClientSecrets = new List<Secret> { new Secret { Value = "secret".Sha256() }},
    Enabled = true,
    AllowedGrantTypes = GrantTypes.Code,
    RedirectUris = { "http://localhost:5003/home" },
    PostLogoutRedirectUris = { "http://localhost:5003/home" },
    AllowedCorsOrigins = { "http://localhost:5003" },
    AllowedScopes =
    {
        IdentityServerConstants.StandardScopes.OpenId,
        IdentityServerConstants.StandardScopes.Profile,
        "Panibus"
    },
    RequirePkce = true,
    AccessTokenType = AccessTokenType.Jwt
}
```

Do I need to provide Redirect Uris and do I need a client secret as I don't see either of those being used, but maybe I am not understanding something about the PKCE flow and those are used?
Currently, it works fine with Implicit flow and Angular, now I'm trying to move on to native-script and Authorization Code flow.

Comment: What is a "native application"? Android? IOS? Windows? Linux? There's no such thing as a "native application"

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto I'm using NativeScript to build it and it will be for Android and IOS

Comment: If you are downvoting, that is ok, but please take the time to explain why you think this question is bad.

Comment: I removed the downvote now that at least someone can know what you are attempting to do. Since you are not building a native application but just a JavaScript one, you should be able to continue using the OIDC JavaScript client. You should use the Hybrid flow instead and use `code id_token` (and `AllowedGrantTypes = GrantTypes.Hybrid;`). By the way, PKCE for public applications is pointless

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto Now you have me very confused, could I chat with you in a private chat to respect the rules of prolonged conversations on SO? I promise not to take a lot of your time.

Comment: Sure: https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/185665/how-to-setup-identity-server-4-with-authorization-code-on-a-nativescript-applicat